# Finding free building height dataset for major cities around world?

Tags: data

I am searching for building/property data which include building height, building area, lot size, and building type classifications(preferably as complete as possible). I am working on an Earthquake Model for highly urbanized locations, especially those around fault lines.

Comment: If asked today, or if in need of any follow up, I think the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange would be the place to ask this.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that even comes close AFAIK is the national cadastre.

[NCD](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/national-cadastre-data-model)

This organization might have part of it. You will likely have to assemble it yourself. 
[National Cadastre dot org](http://nationalcad.org)

Comment: Your link only covers the data model.  Do you have a link to data?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a possible approach few cities have 3d models for many of their buildings in google earth. Perhaps you can check whether these can be downloaded and used in another tool?

http://www.google.com/sketchup/3dwh/index.html

CityGML is an approach to provide such a data in a more standardized way, but I don't think they have much data available.
http://www.citygmlwiki.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach to try and find building heights.

```
https://www.developmentseed.org/blog/2014/08/07/processing-lidar-point-cloud/
```

1. The idea is to download the open street map building footprints dataset.
   Got mine from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/
2. Download lidar data from here: http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/
3. Do a spatial join with the lidar points on the building boundaries
4. Find the max height of the points for each building.

Answer (score 1):

There was a previous question ([Finding footprint data for US buildings?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2046)) just regarding building data. In the USA, Massachusetts has both building data and lot outlines (I'm not sure about building type classifications).

I would also explore [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org) as perhaps this data exists for some countries.

Comment: Yes, in OpenStreetMap (some) buildings are tagged as such. See also this new Wiki page: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Extrude_2D_polygons_to_3D ("Creating a 3D city model" from OpenStreetMap).