# Data source for 3D buildings (germany)

Tags: data, wms, 3d, google-earth

I'm searching for a data base or webservice, that provides **buildings** at a level of detail (LOD) of

1. cuboid (length,width,height) or
2. roof, corners, etc

or better. The area should cover **germany**. 
I've seen very good results at google earth but there seem to be no way to export and use that data.

It'd be nice if the data source is INSPIRE-complient.

Comment: Similar question: [Where can I find free building height dataset for major cities around the world?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/where-can-i-find-free-building-height-dataset-for-major-cities-around-the-world)

Comment: http://www.osm-3d.org/map.htm zoom in to any large German City is in 3D with Buildings

Comment: Google for LoD2 Katastrophenschutz Example: https://www.geoportal-bw.de/tb-gui/details.jsp?blattid=ebc0d190-388e-11e2-81c1-0800200c9a66&sessionid=