# Database of U.S. Buildings

Tags: data, united-states, address, footprint

Does anybody know where I can find a database containing all (or a large percentage of) building addresses in the U.S.? I'm particularly interested in commercial properties.

Perhaps there's a google api I could query for this information?

I was able to find [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/where-can-i-find-building-footprint-data) but it's about finding a database full of building footprints whereas here all I'm concerned about is finding a database full of addresses. It is also five years old.

Comment: If you think that a question is not a duplicate then you should always say specifically why not, and be aware that a question can still be a duplicate no matter its age because older Q&As can and should be improved in preference to re-asking the same question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not capable of improving the answer to the old question myself -- I need help from the community which I'm currently seeking by asking this question.

Comment: We had a recent discussion on this at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-was-asked-but-there-is-no-accepted-answer-for-t  I note that you have sufficient reputation to offer a bounty.

Comment: The fundamental answer remains the same: Structures are a local property, and one comprehensive database does not exist (and would be expensive to maintain)

Comment: If it is a listing of addresses for all (or large percentage - how large?) of the commercial properties in the US then you could focus your question further by specifying the fields that you are looking for, but as Vince says, that would appear not to exist except at a local level.

Comment: [opendata.se] may be an alternative place to ask this question but take their Tour and look at the On-topic page of their Help before asking.

Comment: Right... local data exists such as for [Chicago](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/doit/dataset/boundaries_-_buildings.html) or [DC](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/a657b34942564aa8b06f293cb0934cbd_1) but I doubt a comprehensive one for the whole US.

Comment: Oh I misread your question. Just a list of all **addresses** in the US, not anything location-wise (like building footprints, XY coords or the like)?

Comment: I highly doubt that you can find such a thing. Many counties provide the footprints but it is hard to filter them by use type. Your best shot is with the businesses that deal with this type of stuff, but you will need to pay, it will not be free data.

Answer (score 1):

This was the most comprehensive source of U.S. building addresses I was able to find: http://www.openstreetmap.org.

Quite difficult to say what percentage of buildings are covered but it looks like in most major metropolitan areas the coverage is good. I'd guess 50-100% depending on the city. Coverage appears spottier in rural / suburban areas.